# Spoon inserting into postgres yields "duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

Tags: postgresql, etl, kettle

I have a table in PosgreSQL 9.1.13 that I want to populate with data from a MSSQL. To do that I use PDI 4.4.0.

Postgres and PDI are both running in Ubuntu 13.10.

The table in Postgres is the following:

```sql
create table cobra.facultad (
    id_facultad serial primary key,
    nombre varchar(100),
    id_estado int4 references cobra.estado(id_estado),
    ultima_modificacion_usuario varchar(100),
    ultima_modificacion_fecha timestamp not null default current_timestamp
);
```

The steps I have are:

1. **Table Input 1**: select distinct from a MSSQL view and retrieve `nombre` column.
2. **Table Input 2**: select distinct from `cobra.facultad` table in Postgres and retrieve `nombre` column.
3. **Merge Rows**: merge both flows comparing by `nombre` and get a `flagfield` to determine if its new, identical or deleted.
4. **Synchronize after merge** of Postgres table including in the *Update Fields* ***only*** `nombre` column.

It tests perfect if target table is empty. However if it contained any data, I get the following exception:

```
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inserting row into table [facultad] with values: [1], [Fac. Educación a Distancia], [new]
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inserting/updating row
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «facultad_pkey»
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   Detail: Ya existe la llave (id_facultad)=(1).
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.synchronizeaftermerge.SynchronizeAfterMerge.lookupValues(SynchronizeAfterMerge.java:484)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.synchronizeaftermerge.SynchronizeAfterMerge.processRow(SynchronizeAfterMerge.java:881)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inserting/updating row
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «facultad_pkey»
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   Detail: Ya existe la llave (id_facultad)=(1).
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1411)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1325)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.synchronizeaftermerge.SynchronizeAfterMerge.lookupValues(SynchronizeAfterMerge.java:142)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    ... 3 more
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «facultad_pkey»
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   Detail: Ya existe la llave (id_facultad)=(1).
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2077)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1810)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:498)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:332)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1360)
2014/04/25 13:11:51 - Sync Facultad.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    ... 5 more
```

This means that even if column `id_facultad` was **not specified for insert/update**, spoon tries to insert it with value 1.

The weirdest thing is, if I run the test a second time, I get the same error, but now with value 2. I get the same error until it reaches what should be the table's primary key sequence *nextval*.

Naturally the next thing I tried is the *Add Sequence* step. First I configured it to read the next value of the sequence, then I placed it between *Merge* and *Sync* steps and finally added `id_facultad` column to be inserted/updated.

The result was the same... *Add Sequence* doesn't read the sequence at all.. it starts with 1 and increments on subsequent runs.

I have nothing left to say but **HELP!**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain both input streams to the `Merge rows (diff)` step are sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SERIAL` type just means that `id_facultad` is pointing to a sequence which starts at 1.  Every time a value is retrieved from that sequence, the next value is incremented.

If you insert your own values for `id_facultad`, then it becomes *your* responsibility to update the sequence to a next unused number.  Try:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE id_facultad_seq RESTART WITH (
    SELECT 1+MAX(id_facultad)
    FROM cobra.facultad
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!. I'm not trying to insert my own `id_facultad` values.. in my first attempt I didn't even retrieved that column at all, thinking that spoon wouldn't try to insert it on it's own. In my second attempt, I tried to make _Add Sequence_ step to read the sequence from Postgres, checking the `Use DB to generate the sequence` option. Cheers.

Comment: You were right, the problem was not kettle related... it was the way data was inserted before the transformation was attempted. `id_facultad` was actually specified in an initial `insert` statement. Thanks a lot!